# Why I always get bytes data from server when used python requests module?

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I want to use python requests module to get data from server,but I always get bytes data,even if I had set `headers={'content-type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'}` .

My code:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
headers={'content-type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
#response=requests.get("https://api-dev.creams.io/buildings/2/contract-        templates",headers=headers)
r = requests.get('https://developer.github.com/v3/timeline.json',headers=headers)
print(r.headers)
# response = urlopen("https://beta.creams.io/")
```

when I print headers,`content-type` still be `text/html;charset-utf-8`
and I always get bytes data. when I use `r.text`, I got an error:`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 382: ordinal not in range(128)`. And I used `r.content` method,I always get bytes data(start with `b'`),I just want to get utf-8 encoding string. How can I resolve it?

Comment: You can't get a `UnicodeEncodeError` from decoding data. Your issue is with *encoding*. Look closely at the *full traceback* (include it in your post), and it'll point to the actual line that throws the exception. I suspect it is a `print()` call, or something else that writes out your data to something that requires bytes (your terminal or console requires bytes, for example, and thus Python encodes for you).

Comment: Also, when you talk about *just want to get utf-8 encoded string*, you can only be talking about bytes. UTF-8 is an encoding, where Unicode text is represented in bytes following that standard. Unicode text is not encoded, it is not UTF-anything.

Comment: I think you are right . When I just use `r.text` not used `print()` method . It doesn't have error. But I can't see response from server. How can I make it show？

Comment: @IceWilder try with `sys.stdout.writelines()`

Comment: I use sublime text 3  run python ,and I found I got same error when I print chinese

Comment: @IceWilder: So what does `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)` produce in that setup? Or `import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())` rather. What are you printing *to*? Without information about is supposed to receive the output, we can't help here.

Comment: @Olian04: that'll still need to encode the unicode text to bytes, and that'll fail just the same.

Comment: I had figure out it . I think my sublime config is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This should work just fine:

```
import requests as req
r = req.get('https://developer.github.com/v3/timeline.json')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: still same error .`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhangpenghao/Documents/python/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(r.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 382: ordinal not in range(128)`